# .Net Core API connection refused on port 5000 within Docker Container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I created a .Net Core 3.1 API which I want to run in a Docker container.

The project structure is as follows:

- MyBackendAPI

  - `Dockerfile`
  - `Program.cs`
  - `Startup.cs`
  - Controllers

    - `MailController.cs`
  - ...
- `MyBackendAPI.sln`

In my `MailController.cs`I have a service

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("sendmail/{mailCustomer}/{nameCustomer}/{messageText}")]
public void SendMail(string mailCustomer, string nameCustomer, string messageText)
{
    // do something
}
```

The `Dockerfile` has this content:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN dotnet build
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
```

When I run `docker build . -t dotnetcoreapp` everything works. When I start the container by `docker run dotnetcoreapp` it gives that output.

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Now listening on: http://127.0.0.1:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
    Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
    Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
    Content root path: /app
```

Everything seems to be fine.
But when I request the API in Postman via `http://localhost:5000/mail/sendmail/mymail@mail.com/Edgar/abc` I get `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000`.

By running the command `docker container ls` I see that my container is running and listening on port 5000:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE           COMMAND        CREATED          STATUS          PORTS      NAMES
8abbb2fc90d0   dotnetcoreapp   "dotnet run"   14 minutes ago   Up 14 minutes   5000/tcp   quirky_kirch
```

When I do the same request while my application is not running inside a docker container everything works. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping port 8080 to port 5000, but if you look at the log file your app is listening on port 80. Change the option to -p 80:5000.

Comment: Thank for your hint. I have made a new approach and edited my initial question, you can see it above.